# Calling COM from Intel Fortran?

Tags: fortran, com

I'm trying to get COM working from my Fortran application.  I do a `COMINITIALIZE` followed by a `COMCreateObjectByProgID`. Both of these appear to be successful and return a status of zero. However, when I try to use the COM object, I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in FortranProg01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

I realize that this error can mean almost anything, but has anyone got some suggestions of common problems with COM that produce this problem? My program code:

```
program FortranProg01

use myolepg
implicit none

integer*4 comInitStatus
integer:: comCreateStatus
INTEGER(INT_PTR_KIND()) $OBJECT
INTEGER(4) funcResult
REAL(8) pkgVersion

call COMINITIALIZE(comInitStatus)
print *, comInitStatus

call COMCreateObjectByProgID('MyOlePg.MyOlePkg', $OBJECT, comCreateStatus)
print *, comCreateStatus

funcResult = IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion($OBJECT, pkgVersion)
print *, funcResult

call COMUNINITIALIZE()

end program FortranProg01
```

The wizard-generated interface code:

```
INTERFACE

  !property PackageVersion

    INTEGER(4) FUNCTION IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion($OBJECT, pVal)

    INTEGER(INT_PTR_KIND()), INTENT(IN) :: $OBJECT ! Object Pointer

    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: $OBJECT

    REAL(8), INTENT(OUT) :: pVal 

    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: pVal

  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion

  END FUNCTION IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion

END INTERFACE
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like this was a package-specific problem. More accurately, it was my misunderstanding either of the package or of current Fortran conventions. As far as I can tell, pretty much all of the methods in the package are defined twice, once with a regular name and once with a `$` preface.

So, if I use the `$IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion` call instead of the `IMyOlePkg_GetPackageVersion` call, I get a build warning:

```
ipo: warning #11077: ...: locally defined symbol ... imported
```

but it works! What's particularly interesting is that the `$` method appears simply to add an offset and then call the `non-$` method.

Now whereas I don't really like the warning, and I'd be happy if someone could explain both the warning and the two different calls, I have it working, and if I never get a satisfactory explanation, I can probably learn to live with that.

Answer (score 1):

The non-decorated interface members are just function names but their address is not known at compile time (it could not be known since they are dynamically imported from COM). The linker sets their value to `0x00000000` and that's why you get this error, similar to what happens when dereferencing a `NULL` pointer in C.

As it is written in the Compaq Visual Fortran user guide:

> The interface of a COM member function looks very similar to the interface for
>   a dynamic link library function with one major exception. Unlike a DLL function,
>   the address of a COM member function is never known at program link time.
>   You must get a pointer to an object's interface at run-time, and the address of a
>   particular member function is computed from that.

This is exactly what the decorated versions do. They take `$OBJECT` which is actually a pointer to the object interface, which in turn is a table of addresses to actual object methods that implement the interface (vtable). The decorated function then adds the offset in the vtable of the actual method and *assigns* the resultant address through a pointer and *only then* calls the non-decorated one (which is no longer a `NULL` pointer).

See page 541 (*Calling the Routines Generated by the Module
Wizard*) of the Compaq Visual Fortran user guide available [here](http://jp.xlsoft.com/documents/intel/cvf/cvf_pg.pdf). There is an annotated example of what exactly gets generated and why. Pay attention to annotation 6 of the interface definition (there the pointer to the non-decorated interface member is declared) and to annotation 4 of the decorated function.

Warning `#11077` is the same as [warning LNK4217](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa3se25k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from Microsoft's linker. Probably it is safe to ignore it.

Comment: Note also that the decorated versions adjust the function pointer before _each_ call to the non-decorated version. This is because Fortran 90/95 does not support full object oriented programming (no support for separate instances of the same module) and pointers have to be recomputed for each object. It also means that these functions are not thread-safe.